# How to get the confidence of HaarDetection in python openCV 2.0

Tags: python, opencv

The old version of OpenCV returned the number of neighbors detected, and this could be used as a measure of confidence.

For example:

```
cv.HaarDetectObjects(grayscale, cascade, storage, 1.2, 2,
cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (50,50))
[((174, 54, 114, 114), 53)]
```

The new version of openCV changed the signature used, so now it is either

```
detectMultiScale(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[,
maxSize]]]]]) -> objects
```

or

```
detectMultiScale(image, rejectLevels, levelWeights[, 
scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, 
flags[, minSize[, maxSize[, outputRejectLevels]]]]]]) -> objects
```

The second signature has `rejectLevels` and `levelWeights` which, to my understanding, can be used to get the confidence.

This is a reflection of the c++ version of the functions. But, it is unclear to me how to pass those parameters to be changed in python.
I've tried, for example, the following, which does not change `r` and `w`:

```
r = list()
w = list()
res = cascade2.detectMultiScale(image=img, rejectLevels=r, levelWeights=w)
print res
print r, w

[[ 82 158  53  53]
 [175 157  52  52]
 [103 266 112 112]]
[] []
```

Can anyone explain how to pass `r` and `w` so they will be updated?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, eran?

Comment: Same Issue here.